# How can I interact with the android scripting environment from an android app?

Tags: python, android, ase, android-scripting

I'd like to use python scripts as plugins for an app I'm developing. This seems to be possible by interacting with android-scripting-environment (ASE), as is done by Locale, but I haven't found any documentation about this. How you execute ASE scripts from your own app?

Comment: Might be useful to further explain ASE: http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/

Comment: That ASE website is more confusing than anything. They are gearing towards the user using the platform rather than the developer creating plugins or evaluating scripts. I asked them a simple question s long time ago (about how to use ASE from my app), they promised to respond. They still haven't responded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Locale "plugin" is just recieving a broadcasted `Intent` to `com.twofortyfouram.locale.intent.action.FIRE_SETTING` which includs the script as an `Extra` with the name `com.google.ase.extra.SCRIPT_NAME`.

The relevant bits are in [com.google.ase.locale.LocaleReceiver](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/source/browse/android/AndroidScriptingEnvironment/src/com/google/ase/locale/LocaleReceiver.java).